# How to build-in Syncfusion community license

Tags: .net, syncfusion

I downloaded Syncfusion community components (in particular my primary concern is **xlsio** component) and want to use my community license for xlsio PCL component and didn't quite get how to build it in. I expected there should be something like SetLicenseKey(key), but I failed to find such method in their API. I want to make sure that I won't get trial expired message in my production app. How to build-in community license in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No longer true. Since 16.2.0.x you need to download license and apply it like I asked in the question:

```
Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense("YOUR LICENSE KEY");
```

More info can be found [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/common/essential-studio/licensing/license-key).

Comment: so, a  licensing error  could pop up in a production app?

Comment: @PabloGonzalez, yes, it can show error at production, you'd better test in debug. Xlsx export shows empty document with licensing error text.

Comment: but, if I had my license key in the production app, it will be no problem right?

Comment: @PabloGonzalez yes, no problem with a key.

Comment: I am getting this error. The name SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense does not exist in current context, even after I have installed nuget package for Syncfusion.Licensing. I am using asp.net core web api and want to use excel export. thanks

Comment: @MindRoasterMir maybe they removed it again. Give it a try in release mode.

Comment: No. It worked. I was just trying it in the wrong place. In my Controller, it should be in the Startup.cs as it is also mentioned it in official docs and I overlooked it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Syncfusion controls and frameworks do not typically implement runtime licensing. There is no need to set such a key when compiling for deployment.

I work for Syncfusion.

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Confirmed. I use these without issue.

Comment: @Daniel Jebaraj referring to the new licensing rules, could you confirm that a licensing error will not pop up in a production app if the RegisterLicense method is included?